# Bootstrap Modal in a SQL While Statement keeps displaying the first record contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am a newbie. I am converting a working Bootstrap modal that contains a post form. The modal opens using a button with an Id. It always displays the FORM contents of the first record found in the SQL while statement results list when opened. I changed the modal from id to a class. I open it now with a class button and not an id button. But now it keeps displaying the Form contents of the 2nd record. If I take the form out of the modal it works fine and displays the right contents. The accept-btn opens the modal. The ('. confirm-body') contains the Modal content Form.  Appreciate some help please.

```html
<!-- Opens modal is outside the modal-->
<a class="accept-btn">Accept</a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content animate confirmarea-size">
    <div id="topblue-border1" class="topblue-border1"></div> <!-- topblue border End -->
    <!-- Popup buttons Start -->  
    <div class="confirm-body boxshadow" style="display:none;">
      <form class="whatever" action="" method=""> 
        <input type="hidden" class="whatever" name="" value="<?php echo whatever?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" class="whatever" name="" value="<?php echo whatever?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="whatever" name="" value="<?php echo whatever?>">
        <div class="ajax-response"></div>
        <a><div id="css-btn" class="confirm-btn">Accept</div></a>
        <a><div id="css-btn" class="cancel-btn">Cancel</div></a>
        <a><div id="css-btn" class="nextstage-btn">OK</div></a>
      </form>   
    </div> <!-- Popup Confirm Section END --> 
  </div> <!-- End of The Modal Content -->      
</div> <!-- End of The Modal -->


1st Option Button script
<script>
// Accept button Opens the Modal .
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accept-btn').click(function(event) {
    $('.modal').show();
    $('.confirm-body').show();
  });
});
</script>

2nd Option button  script.  I want to try something like this but I dont know how to code it and close it correctly. each recored has a record Id field.  I want to relate the modal to the record id.

<script>
//Accept Bid Button Opens the Modal and displays the Confirm-Body Div.
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.acceptbid-btn').click(function(event){ 
var myModal = "myModal" + $('.recordid').val();
$  $(this).closest('recordid').find('modal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        return false;
$('.confirm-body').show();


});
});
});

</script>


UPDATE:
I have done this using php.  The button and the modal ids 
now matches the Row record id. And will always be unique. 
I am going some where with this idea, not sure yet I am 
yet to test what happens.

<?php  $buttonid = $recordid;?>
 <a  id="<?php echo $buttonid;?>" class="acceptbid-btn"></a>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="<?php echo $buttonid;?>" class="modal">
```

Comment: try this: $(event.target).parents(".modal");

Comment: Thanks Jaber, I am new to this.  on which line do apply this please

Comment: I applied  what you told me Jabber and it did not work but thanks. I don't think ajax may help in this case. The Modal  is the issue becuase when I take the form out of the Modal  it displays correctly and posts correctly.   I even put the form in a Php variable and echoed it in a variable  in the modal and  the modal displayed the incorrect record info.  I think I need  to change this to CSS /PHP issue thanks.

Comment: I may have to  send  a GET request to php server using AJAX, and then replace content of modal using html property of element.  Its a solution ,  but I want to  hear of other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue.  Some methods to get around it were good like the AJAX GET  Posted here which works.   But I knew there must be another way which will not require a AJAX GET command but rather make minor changes to the Modal and Because my other problem is my other modal on another project contains an user input field in the modal form that returns Js queries to the open mondal before posting the form via Ajax .  After lots of testing  and pain I found the solution as i knew the answer lay in The Modal ID being static. How could I make it Dynamic and match the SQL $row id and Button ID.  The answer lies below.

- 1. Create at php variable that contains the Sql database  `$row [recordid]`  or id for the row.   That is now the variable that is needed to make sure  you are getting the right data.

`$id  =     "". $row["id"]."";`

- 2. In the button you use to  open the Modal echo the record id Variable. KEEP! the hash# before the variable:  `<button type="button" class="accept-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $id;?>">`
- 3. The Modal Div - Remove #myModal and echo the id php variable. DON'T put a hash#
     `<div id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="modal">`

Thats it done.  So When you click the modal button in any row it will display the correct content/form.